# Does it make sense to power multiple 12V devices from one single power source?

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a number of devices (External hard disks, switches, router) on my desk. Each ones comes with a own power supply. This leads to a waste of space and a mess with all the cables.

**Does it make sense to power all devices from a single power source?**

I would simple buy a power supply which provides enough current to power all devices and would connect all the cables to this single power supply.

Are there any risks in doing this? Are there important things to pay attention to?

Comment: Single point of failure, plus single point of risk for all devices when the PSU mishaps.

Comment: THIS IS ON TOPIC, READ THE SITE SCOPE

Comment: Remember, this is exactly what is done inside a typical server tower. Multiple drives and devices powered by a single power supply.

Comment: @Passerby This is an interesting hint, a PC power supply could be a reliable solution.

Comment: @Passerby - (1) Thanks. (2) So flag for reopening, if able. Assuming not too busy drawing wire, smelting silicon, boiling hooves and .... :-)

Comment: This is necessarily a design question. You CANNOT buy an off the shelf solution. Why does anyone think this is an unacceptable question? (That's a real question).

Comment: Deleting comments without responding to the technical points raised is "a bit sad".

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thank you, but just let it be. I'm glad I got plenty of good answers and hints. Now I will go and DESIGN the power supply solution. ;-) As a design I plan to use 5-10 3.5mm jacks at the power supply, each with individual fuses. Hope this will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea has reasonable merit.
No utterly major show stopper but things to think about.

The arrangement is non standard. You need a 12V distribution hub with appropriate sockets. These MAY vary between devices. You could always replace plugs that do not fit your standard but this is annoying at least.

You still need all the cables. With mains feed to plug-packs you can cluster the groups of packs but with your scheme all power cords must reach your hub. You could have sub-hubs but then risk voltage drop due to extra cabling - voltage drop is higher at low voltage for the same power.

As PlasmaHH says - adding single point failure mode is undesirable. Worse, as he also notes, if the psu ever went high-output you could have a grand Y'All come peripherals barbecue. Or worse.

I have about 20 x 12V devices in use here  - mostly multi Terrabyte hard drives.
A substantial open cage supply may be rated at 12V, 250 Watts - or about 20A. Many devices use a 1A x 12v supply but some use 2A or 3A supplies. So in my case I'd need at least 2 x 250 W supplies. YMMV.

I have never had a plugpack fail in my "hive". I have shelves of external drives or other equipment with plug-packs on a lower shelf close to their drive. Cords can be neatly tied. Various spiral or apparently spiral plastic sleeves can be bought to tame the wires.

Answer (score 3):

Some COTS solution may exist and you can work based on those. For 12V distribution, automotive cigarette lighter jack may be appropriate; and for 5V, you have USB.

I have a power brick that takes mains input and gives me regulated 12V with a standard automotive cigarette lighter jack. This makes 12V distribution using one of those 12V distribution hubs for automotive use appropriate for me.

My 5V distribution is based on externally powered USB hubs - I have 3 of them, and they actually all connected to my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is done frequently by the end user in the amateur radio hobby.  The only reason it's not done for consumer computer devices is that no one can agree on any standards.

However, it's slowly coming around via USB chargers.  For instance, I have the following charger:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00OJ79UK6/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OJ79UK6)

Computer peripherals simply use power from USB, and with the new higher power USB standard I expect manufacturers to stop using external power supplies altogether except for unusually high power devices.

If you want to do this with 12 volts, I'd suggest following amateur radio suggestions - they won't all apply to your specific needs, but you'll find they have a few standard connector types, power supplies, and fused distribution designs that should simplify it for you.

Make sure you are sufficiently fused (ie, you could short out any wire and a fuse would blow long before the wire melted its insulation) and you should be safe.